# Cast of the List<String> to List<T> in Kotlin

Tags: casting, kotlin

I need to create a generic method that splits a string and casts values

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> convertFromString(myString: String) : List<T>{
    val castedList = ArrayList<T>()
    for(item in  myString.split(";")){
        castedList.add(item as T)
    }
    return castedList
}
```

I call this method `convertFromString<Int>("1;2;3;4;5;6")` and expect to have output `List<Int>` but it fails during the cast `item as T`.

How can I cast all values to generic `T`?

Comment: `item as T` works only if item "is a" `T`. In this case, though, `item` is a `String` and `T` is an `Int`, so `String as Int` fails. The only possible solution that comes to my mind is something like "if T is an Int -> castedList.add(item.toInt())"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would rather suggest you to supply a transformation function, e.g.

```
inline fun <T: Any> convertFromString(myString: String, transformation: (String) -> T)
                                                      = myString.split(";")
                                                                .map(transformation)
                                                                .toList()
```

Note that you can't cast the `String` to anything else then `String` that is why `item as T` will not work. With the transformation function you ensure that it is transformed correctly (as long as you do not use `item as T` as the transformation ;-)).

Some sample usages/transformation functions could be:

```
val doubleList = convertFromString("123;123") { it.toDouble() }
val intList = convertFromString("123;123") { it.toInt() }
val objList = convertFromString("data=123;data=444") { yourParser.parse(it) }
```

Additionally with that approach you do not require the `reified` anymore. The `inline` however is still useful for any function containing a lambda function.